# Logarithmic Differentiation with powers to powers

Tags: calculus

So I have $ y = 3^{x^2} $ and I need to differentiate it logarithmically, but when I do it I get $$y'= 2x \  4^{x^2}  \ln 3 $$ but the answer says it's $3^{x^2}  \ln 9 $.

Any ideas as to where I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y = 3^{x^2} \Rightarrow \log (y) = \log (3^{x^2}) = x^2 \log 3 \\ \Rightarrow \frac{y'}{y} = 2x \log 3$$

But $y = 3^{x^2}$ so we must have $$y' = 2x\ 3^{x^2} \log 3 =  \ 3^{x^2} x\ \log 9$$

You missed an $x$ by the way.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Let $$y=3^{x^2}$$ Take logarithms $$\log(y)=x^2\log(3)$$ and differentiate; so $$\frac{y'}{y}=2x \log(3)$$

I am sure that you can take from here.